# „Own goal“ auf Deutsch

Tags: meaning, abbreviation, loanword

Im heutigen Spiel (Wales gegen Nordirland) hat der Verteidiger der Nordiren ein Tor in das eigene Netz geschossen. Auf Englisch heißt es *own goal* oder *auto-goal*.

In der Information zum Spiel (im *Ersten*) steht:

> 75' Gareth McAuley (OG)

Was bedeutet eigentlich **OG**?
Ist das eine deutsche Abkürzung oder ein Lehnwort aus dem Englischen?

Comment: Da ARD und ZDF ja auch nur den UEFA World Feed anzeigen, wird dort natürlich international auf Englisch eingeblendet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Das ist die direkte Übertragung des englischen *own goal* mitsamt der dazugehörigen Abkürzung *OG*.

Das deutsche (besser: *in Deutschland verwendete*) Wort dafür ist ein *Eigentor*. Auf deutschen Spielberichten werden Eigentore (in Sportarten, in denen sie auftreten können) als [*ET*](http://abkuerzungen.woxikon.de/abkuerzung/et.php) abgekürzt.

Comment: Vielen Dank für die sehr detalierte Erklärung, die auch nur 1,5 Minuten dauerte :-) Das ist difinitiv die Antwort.

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown Ich weiß, ich war sehr langsam ;) Das geht schneller! ;)

Comment: in CH (und AT?) wird es teilweise (!) auch als Eigengoal bezeichnet :)

Comment: Stimmt, ich stelle nur die Situation in Deutschland dar @npe